# Jenkins credentials

Tags: jenkins

Есть необходимость подтягивать логин и пароль в pipeline хранящиеся в шифрованном файле вместе с проектом. Есть ли возможность это реализовать совместно с withCredentials?

Comment: Или же, существует какая-то возможность протягивать credentials в вызываемую (дочернюю джобу )?

Comment: результат работы функции `withCredentials()` — дополнительные переменные в окружении. то же самое может сделать и, например, [плагин envinject](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin). ну а если вы используете pipeline-ы, то там вообще простор для скриптования (а упомянутый плагин не нужен да и не работает).